# page-object gem seems not working

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I am trying to use page-object gem in my watir-webdriver scripts and I think I might be missing something.

Here is my code for log_in.rb:
require "./all_deals"

```
class LogIn
  include PageObject

  text_field(:email, :id => 'UserName')
  text_field(:password, :id => 'Password')
  checkbox(:remember_me, :id => 'RememberMe')
  button(:log_me_in, :value => 'Login')

  def initialize(browser)
    @browser = browser
  end

  def log_in (email, password)
    self.email = email
    self.password = password
    remember_me
    log_me_in
    AllDeals.new(@browser)
  end
end
```

My home_page.rb

```
require "./log_in"

  class HomePage

    def initialize(browser)
      @browser = browser
    end

    def visit
      @browser.goto "http://treatme.co.nz/"
    end

    def go_to_log_in
      @browser.goto "https://treatme.co.nz/Account/LogOn"
      LogIn.new(@browser)
    end
  end
```

Here is my log_in_test.rb

```
require "rubygems"
require "test/unit"
require "watir-webdriver"
require "page-object"
require "./home_page"


class LogInTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @browser ||= Watir::Browser.new :firefox
  end

  def teardown
   @browser.close
  end

  def test_fail
    @home_page = HomePage.new(@browser)
    @home_page.visit
    @log_in_page = @home_page.go_to_log_in
    @all_deals = @log_in_page.log_in("test@gmail.com","test")
    assert (@all_deals.get_title == "GrabOne Daily Deals - Buy Together, Save Together")
  end
end
```

The result of the test run is:

```
Finished tests in 22.469286s, 0.0445 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
test_fail(LogInTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `text_field_value_set' for nil:NilClass
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/page-object-0.9.2/lib/page-object/accessors.rb:142:in `block in text_field'
```

I am using Ruby 1.9 with page-object gem 0.9.2.

Can you please help me?

Also in each of those rb file, I need to require the class files it references, is there a way I don't have to declare it every time?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Addressing the Exception**

That exception is occurring do to the LogIn page re-defining the initialize method.

```
class LogIn
  include PageObject

  def initialize(browser)
    @browser = browser
  end
end
```

When you include PageObject, it already adds a specific initialization method. Your class is overriding that initialization and presumably causing something to not get setup correctly.

Removing the `initialize` method will get you past that exception.

However, you will then hit a `remember_me` is not a variable/method exception. Assuming you want to check the checkbox, it should be `check_remember_me`.

**Requiring Class Files**

I usually have my test file require a file that requires all my page_objects. It is a similar concept to how your would require any other gem or library.

For example, I would create a `treatme.rb` file with:

```
require 'log_in'
require 'home_page'
```

Assuming you require the files in the required order (ie files that are needed by others are required first), none of your page object files (ie log_in.rb and home_page.rb) should need to do any requiring.

Your test files would then just require your treatme.rb file. Example:

```
require './treatme'
```

Comment: Hi Justin, I appreciate your reply. I remove the initialize statement from my log_in.rb, and it worked. But I am sorry I really dont understand why. Because in my LogIn class, method log_in does use @browser local variable. But I removed the initialize to declare this variable, why it is not complaining?

Comment: When you do `include PageObject`, it automatically adds an `initialize` method to your class (see the [code](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/master/lib/page-object.rb#L59)). If you follow that code, you will actually see that it also does the `@browser = browser`.