# WATIR: how to use two or multiple visit() in one step definition?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

```
  Background:
    Given the Seller has generated a coupon
      | pre-requisite                        | status|
      | Coupon generated                     | Yes   |
      | Activate Coupon                      | Yes   |

    And I login as a customer

  Scenario: Customer can use coupon for shopping
    When I am on an existing product created by Seller
    When I click on insert coupon code
    Then xyz abc qwert lorem ipsum
```

This is my `.feature` file and `scenario`. Here in this `.feature` file 3 user's login & logout are needed. 
When 3rd time a user is asked to login(in a `scenario`) it doesnt go to login page using `visit`.

These are the instances when login is required:

1. Given the Seller has generated a coupon #Seller log in to generate coupon
2. And I login as a customer # customer login
3. When I am on an existing product created by Seller #
   Seller login again to create the product and then customer logs in and goes to product page. In this step `visit` doesnt work.

For login I am using:
`visit(LoginPage).login_as_seller` and `visit(LoginPage).login_as_customer` these methods has written like this:

```
def login_as_seller
    if $if_logged_in == true
      sign_out
    end
    login(FigNewton.seller_userid, FigNewton.seller_password)
  end
```

LoginPage rb file:

```
class LoginPage
  include PageObject

  page_url("#{FigNewton.base_url}/login")

 def login_as_seller
    if $if_logged_in == true
          sign_out
        end
        login(FigNewton.seller_userid, FigNewton.seller_password)
      end
end
```

I have noticed that if method `login` is called in `Background` then it works but in `Scenario` its doesn't, but Why this is happening I don't know. Please help me out here. I read this [page-object gem seems not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473510/page-object-gem-seems-not-working) but no help.

Comment: @All what I have noticed is true, if there are multiple `visit` in one step def then it fails visit has to be separate in separate step defs. **But why and how to fix this?**

Comment: I do not see why using `visit` multiple times would cause an issue and was not able to reproduce it when I tried. It would help if you could share a minimal working example that shows the problem.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you mean by "doesn't work"?  What is your stack trace error?